# How do I prevent dragging a page through the phone's touch?

Tags: javascript, css

How can I prevent dragging a page when scrolling the range slider? 
[Example page](https://whoisandy.github.io/react-rangeslider/)

Are there ways besides - To press and hold for a couple of seconds, and only then move?

[image]

Comment: I don't see that problem (IOS iPad) - what system are you using?

Comment: iOs iPhone 6 and Chrome browser. The page stands still if you click on the circle and hold it for a short time. And if you move it right away, it moves along with the page

Comment: I think that the problem is that you have scrollbar at the bottom. Try to add css `* { outline: 1px solid red; }` you probably have something that go outside your viewport. Connect Chrome debug tools and inspect the page to find the element that is outside.

Answer (score 5):

You need to disable the touch action on the relevant elements.

In CSS:

```
  touch-action: none;
```

Comment: @OmarOmeiri I had exactly the same feeling, spent more than half a day banging my head against the wall trying to get it to work and in the end all that was needed was this... No idea why this was so hard to find, so at least I put this answer up in the hopes of sparing some people the journey I went through